# Access array list item by name using jq

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, jq

Consider the following json data, sourced from from Docker image `nginx:1.25-bookworm`:

```
# docker pull nginx:1.25-bookworm
# docker image inspect 81be38025439 | jq '.[].Config.Env'
[
  "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "NGINX_VERSION=1.25.3",
  "NJS_VERSION=0.8.2",
  "PKG_RELEASE=1~bookworm"
]
#
```

I would like to be able to access '1.25.3' from this list to tag the image in a build step of a CI-CD pipeline.

I am close to my goal with the following:

```
# docker image inspect 0743972990c7 | jq -r '.[].Config.Env[1]'
NGINX_VERSION=1.23.4
```

But would like to know how to access the item 'NGINX_VERSION' by name instead of relying on the assumption that it will be the second environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So filter NGINX_VERSION  from the array and remove it.

```
.[].Config.Env |
select(startswith("NGINX_VERSION=")) |
sub("^NGINX_VERSION="; "")
```

Answer (score 3):

For the task given, I'd also go with `startswith` as described in [KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77474109/2158479). But if you need to access multiple values, you might want to consider creating a lookup object using `INDEX`:

```bash
INDEX(.[:index("=")]) as $ix   # stores {"PATH": … , "NGINX_VERSION": … , …}
```

and then access the values by field name (truncate by the `index` position of the first `=` character):

```bash
| $ix["NGINX_VERSION"]         # yields "NGINX_VERSION=1.25.3"
| .[index("=")+1:]             # yields "1.25.3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fn5gOiiOj8W)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful function for converting an array of strings of the form `key<DELIM>value` to a JSON obejct:

```
# input: an array of strings of the form: key + delim + value
# It is assumed that delim is string with a single character that 
# is not special in the context of regular expressions.
def toObject(delim): 
  map( capture("(?<key>[^" + delim + "]*)" + delim + "(?<value>.*)" )) | from_entries;
```

A solution to the stated problem can then be written as:

```
toObject("=") | .NGINX_VERSION
```